# Razorpay.validateWebhookSignature() is not working for invoice.paid events

Tags: node.js, razorpay

Razorpay.validateWebhookSignature() returns true for other webhook events but for events type "invoice.paid" it is returning false.

I am using Razorpay npm package

Here is a code snippet

```
    let body = req.body;
    let receivedSignature = req.get("x-razorpay-signature");
    let secret = "xxxx";

    var success = Razorpay.validateWebhookSignature(
      JSON.stringify(body),
      received_signature,
      secret
    );
```

success is returning true for all events except 'invoice.paid'

Comment: may be there is some permisson issue, check razorpay dashboar to provide required access to your api key.

Comment: @mehta-rohan, i dont think this will be the case cause for all the events its working fine except invoice

Comment: It's fine, sometimes you just need additional access to some transactions.

Comment: have you tried this package? I mean, I am not able to see any extra permission required for invoice events

Comment: https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-node/issues/96#issuecomment-521374813

Answer (score 0):

on second line you are declearing variable:

```js
let receivedSignature = req.get("x-razorpay-signature");
```

and on razorpay function you are passing : received_signature,
So, it is bound to work as unexpected, as received_signature is not defined.